# signing colored assets to identify worthwhile assets

Tags: multi-signature, signature, colored-coins

With colored coin and similar solutions, anyone can create an asset. Using counterparty as an example, this gets out of control very quickly with no way to determine "good" assets easily (http://www.blockscan.com/asset.aspx)

Lets assume people are dealing with shares of centralized corporations, instead of distributed autonomous ones, could a multisig or any signing solution using an institution that people trust be used to "sign" all assets that institution likes?

With multisig, I could imagine an issuer wouldn't be able to finish creating the asset until the trusted institution also signed the transaction, this would mimic securities issuance in the regulated markets.

For instance, FINRA signed the asset and there is an aggregator that looks for FINRA signatures + color. And then people would know that this asset has some kind of recourse behind it if things didn't work out.